# CodeIgniter Array Text Input Form Validation

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, validation

In CodeIgniter when validating an array of text input fields is it possible to get each array index for the error message?

I have (by default) three fields, the first two are required, and more fields and be dynamically added or removed.

```
<input name="url[]" value="" type="text">
<input name="url[]" value="" type="text">
<input name="url[]" value="" type="text">
```

Right now I loop through the input arrays

```
foreach ($data ['urls'] as $idx => $url)
{
    $num = $idx + 1; // counting number
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('url[' . $idx . ']', 'Url ' . $num, 'trim|callback_validate_input_url[ ' . $idx . ' ]');
}
```

Instead of

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('url[]', 'URL', 'trim|callback_validate_input_url');
```

and I validate it with a custom call back

```
public function validate_input_url ( $uri, $position )
{
    if ( $position <= 1 && !$uri ) // check if it's the first two input arrays and if they're empty
    {
        $this -> form_validation -> set_message('validate_input_url', 'This field cannot be empty');
        return false;
    }

    if ( $position >= 2 && !$uri )
        return true; // true if it's the third or later optional URL

    $pattern = '/^http:\/{2}.*/';
    // must start with http://
    if ( !preg_match($pattern, $uri) )
    {

        $this -> form_validation -> set_message('validate_input_url', 'This field must have a valid URL');
        return false;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

That way I can get the error message for the input that generated the error

```
<?php 
    foreach ($urls as $idx => $url) {
?>
    <input type="text" name="url[]" value="<?php echo $url ?>">
    <?php echo form_error('url[' . $idx . ']'); ?>
<?php 
} ?>
```

So is there a way to get the error message for the input field that generated the error without having to loop through all the input fields and attaching a rule for each one individually? I looked through the docs and I didn't see anything about it. So I'm not sure if I overlooked something or if the way I'm doing it is the only way.

Comment: validation_errors() is similiar to the form_error(), except it allows you to format the HTML around the error. I want/need to be able to get the error for the input field where the error occurred, not just arbitrarily say there was an error on some field(s) - without having to loop through the submitted URLs first to assign an individual rule to them.

Answer (score 0):

You question sounds like you are asking, "is there a way to see what caused an error, without checking everything that might have caused the error." If that is the question, the answer is no. You have to assign validation rules to each input, and then if you want to find the one (or more) that caused an error, you have to search them. You can simplify your approach somewhat by using Sets of Validation Rules which are explained here https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html but I don't see how you will avoid checking each thing that could cause an error to see what caused an error. In general, your approach seems fine, why do you want to change it?